# Type input characters in html form need match - jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

How do I type in a HTML textbox and if the first 3 characters dont match a set variable - then display an error? I need to lose the error and display text next to the input after the 3rd character

I'm thinking jQuery, AJAX, PHP - not sure.  I just don't want to use an alert box.

And this needs to be before a user enters the submit button...

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="test"/><br>
    <input type="button" id="txt" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txt").click(function(){
        var text = $("#test").val();
        var comparingText = "yes";

        if (text != comparingText){
            alert( $("#test").val());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you asking what tech you should use?

Answer (score 2):

It will show this alert after write yes.
you can use it as you want.

```
$( "#test" ).keyup(function() {
    var test = $( "#test" ).val();
    if(test == 'yes'){
      alert( "your Error msg" );
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<span>` element, next to the `<input>` element to display an error message and, as you said, avoid using the alert box.

**JS**

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="test" oninput="submitData(this.value)"/> 
    <span id="textError"></span><br/>
    <input type="button" id="txt" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS

```
function submitData(input) {        
    if (input != "yes") {
        document.getElementById("textError").innerHTML = "Your Error MSG";  
    } else {
        document.getElementById("textError").innerHTML = "";    
    }
}
```

**JS + jQuery**

In this case I'm taking [Mamunur Rashid](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37756112/revisions)'s answer to complement the code.

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="test"/> <span id="textError"></span><br/>
    <input type="button" id="txt" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").keyup(function(){
        var test = $("#test").val();
        if (test != "yes") {
            $("#textError").html("Your Error MSG"); 
        } else {
            $("#textError").html("");   
        }
    });
});
```